# Add effects to splitted words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add some effects with jQuery to splitted words, but I don't really know how to handle this.

My code starts as it follows:

```
    $(window).load(function() { 
        var str = $("#animated_text h1").text();
        var substr = str.split(' ');

        $.each(substr, function(index, value) {
            value.fadeIn();
            value.animate({});
        });
    });
```

Thanks for every suggestions

Comment: value is just a string, so it won't have a jQuery object.  The next step would be to put the value into a span or div object, append that to something and then fade it in and animate it.

Comment: All you are getting is the text contained in the element, not the element itself, so fading it will do nothing!

Comment: @lgt: Wrap each word in a span, then you'll be able to style the spans sequentially (or otherwise).

Comment: try this:  value.wrap('<span></span>').fadeIn().animate({...});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split words and create element for each word. Please find the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/diode/DLx2A/21/

```
    var str = $("#animated_text h3").text();
    var substr = str.split(' ');


    $("#animated_text h3").remove();


    var wordCount = 0;

    $.each(substr, function(index, value) {

        var $word = $("<h3>" +  value  + "</h3>");
        $word.appendTo("#animated_text");
        $word.delay(index * 100).animate({"font-size":"30px"}).animate({"font-size":"16px"} , function(e){

            wordCount++;

            if(wordCount == $("#animated_text h3").size()){
               $("#animated_text").empty().text(substr.join(" "));
            }


        });

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
  var str = $("#animated_text h1").text();
  var substr = str.split(' ');
  $.each(substr, function(index, value) {
    // you can animate elements, not raw text
    // add your value to an inline element and fade it in
    $('<span>'+value+'</span>').appendTo('body').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind though (if I recall correctly) fadeIn/fadeOut use `display:block`, so text for a header would then become broken up by lines.

Comment: Just tested it out :-) . jQuery actually just strips the display property altogether on fadeIn. If it does a fadeOut on an element, it keeps track of the display property and reverts back to that on fadeIn. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/MfcEd/2/

Answer (score 0):

`value` is `string`, you cant apply `fadeIn` or `animate` on it.

may be you want to do something like:

```
$('#'+value).fadeIn();
$('#'+value).animate({});
```

if **value** is an **id** of a **element**.